# How to find the general and particular solution to this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure how the equation should look like for the general and particular solution, so I'm confused how to solve it. What is y1 and y2 suppose to be even?
[image]

Comment: Second part involves substitution and solving the equations.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $n$ linearly independent solutions for an order $n$ Linear Ordinary Differential Equation, then the general solution is the set of linear combinations of those. Since $y_1$ and $y_2$ are indeed linearly independent, the general solution for this case is indeed $a y_1 + b y_2$

$y_1$ is a particular solution ($a=1, b=0$). So is $y_2$ (for $a=0, b=1$) You need to find the one that satifies the conditions

Comment: I think that your answer assumes that the ODE is linear, which is not given in the above exercise.

Comment: @Jan The question cannot be answered otherwise

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point out that you assume this without mention it. A priori, your answer is false.

Comment: @Jan : There is no class of second order homogeneous equations in the fractional sense (at least, none with an associated solution method), so the word "homogeneous" in the task implies linear.